# Multilingual interface, can we have it?

Tags: feature-request

I believe Russian.SE would benefit greatly from having an alternative Russian interface. Can this be achieved? Does the SE engine allow us to have the same content (FAQ, badge descriptions, page text, etc) in multiple languages? Translating the FAQ and the controls at least should be a priority.

Comment: From http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-languages-should-we-use-for-the-site: It's unlikely that the interface could be translated. Both french.SE and german.SE have tried to convince the SE team to do so, unsuccessfully

Comment: I wouldn't give up hope, but I would make it a long-term wish. Like at some point in the future when at least a couple of the language SE's "graduate" out of beta.

Comment: @iHunter That comment is untrue; see my response there.

Comment: @balpha Got it, thanks

Comment: isn't it a question for SE meta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is our goal to make Stack Exchange a much more multi-national network. Allowing international characters in tags is our first priority, and those development efforts are underway.

But *yes*, we *will* provide a localized interface which will allow communities to translate the interface into their native language, but that is further down our "localization" schedule.

Localization is coming, but I do not have any dates report… or even a wildly-arbitrary estimate.